# Outlook addin says "still running" after addin has comleted

Tags: office-js

When testing my outlook addin in outlook desktop.  And if I go to close outlook, it prompts saying "Add-ins are still running on Outlook.   Do you want to wait for them to finish?".

This is after my addin has completed.  My addin is written in typescript (if that makes any difference).

I cut my addin back to try and find the issue, and now the only thing it is doing is "console.log('test')" and thats it. when you click my GUI-less addin, its just a button in the ribbon, it prints that message in my visual studio debug window, and thats it.

When I go to close outlook, it says its still running.

Is there a method or some way I can tell outlook that no, the addin has completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure to call event.completed() to notify outlook that the current uiless code has been completed. You can find more details in [this article](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/functionfile?product=outlook).